# Prism Xamarin How to access my grid at runtime

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism-4

I am developing with Prism library and Xamarin, I want to create a table which will be able to add new rows and fill the content in the new rows.

It seems there is no table control, and I made a test with Grid, I defined the Grid at xaml like below:

```
        <Grid x:Name="SourceGrid" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

But, how can I access this Grid after my application lauch at runtime.

I want to add new row while runtime.

Answer (score 0):

First google for such made controls, there are some available from the community. Second please kindly read about creating xamarin custom controls it will answer much.

For the direct answer:

You can access its `SourceGrid.Children` with methods like `SourceGrid.Children.Add(view, col, row);`

Comment: I just used `SourceGrid` at xaml, what should I define at code behide?

Comment: For what purpose? Usually you define your table totally in xaml or create a custom control where you can build it from scratch from code behind..

Comment: First I would design the xaml with table structure, and then, during runtime, i would suggest you add row dynamically, I want to provide a way for user to enter data row by row. For complete create control in code, how could I decide where to place it.